# R par(omd) does not contain within mfrow

Tags: r

I would like two plots to show up in two seperate spaces in the plot so I do:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(1:10,1:10)
```

Now I would like the second plot to be about 25% shorter than the first plot so I adjust omd:

```
tmp <- par()$omd
tmp[4] <- 0.75
par(omd=tmp)
plot(1:10,1:10)
```

The problem is that the second plot shows up ontop of the first plot. How do I avoid this margin issue?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try using `layout` instead?

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 2), ncol = 2L), widths = c(1,1),heights = c(0.5,1))
par(mar = c(3,2,2,2))
plot(1:10,1:10)
par(mar = c(3,2,2,2))
plot(1:10,1:10)
```

[image]

I guess maybe you'd want to set the heights to `c(0.2,0.8)` to get a 25% reduction?

*Edit*

But I don't think that `omd` does what you think it does. It changes the region *inside* the outer margins, which will always include *both* plot regions when setting `par(mfrow = c(1,2))`. What you really want to change, I think is `plt`, which alters the  size of the *current* plotting region (using `quartz`, as I'm on a mac):

```
quartz(width = 5,height = 5)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
vec <- par("plt")
plot(1:10,1:10)
par(plt = vec * c(1,1,1,0.75))
plot(1:5,1:5)
```

Comment: mar works with mfrow also. its omd thats not working because of the normalized device coordinates. And I have to use mfrow because I don't know how many plots will be there

Comment: @Ellipsis... Ok, I guess I was making things too complicated. Just setting `mar` and increasing the top margin for the second plot should work.

Comment: I want to use omd because then I can input percentages mar will not work for me unless I can somehow calculate what the width should be from the percentage